# No me realiza el INSERT INTO en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un código sencillo, pero no logro que realice la función `INSERT`, mi base de datos se llama `test`, con una tabla llamada `login` y 2 columnas llamadas `usuario y`password`, si alguien me pudiera orientar sobre el proceso que estoy realizando mal le estaria muy agradecido.

El script realiza la acción *(redirigir a `login.php`)* pero no se actualiza.

config.php

```php
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn) 
{
    die("No hay conexión: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nombre = $_POST["txtusuario"];
$pass = $_POST["txtpassword"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO login(nombre, password) VALUES ('".$nombre."','".$pass."')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "Se guardo"





?>
```

Y este es el archivo index:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>StaffMx</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normalize.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>        
        <center>
            <form method="post" action="config.php">
                <div>
                    <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="contenedor">    
                    <div>
                        <img src="logo.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <table class="tablagrande">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgb(136, 139, 139); padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:5px;">
                                <label><center>Ingresar</center> </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label><center>Usuario</center></label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center><input type="text" name="txtusuario" class="in"/></center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label><center>Password</center></label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center><input type="password" name="txtpassword" class="in"/></center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center><input type="submit" value="Entrar!" class="in"/></center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A simple vista veo un typo `mysqli_query($con,$Sql);` la variable debe ser `$sql` en minúscula. Por otro lado, recomiendo [guardes las contraseñas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240973/how-long-is-the-sha256-hash) cifradas `$pass = sha256($_POST["txtpassword"]);` y a la hora de hacer login, cifras del mismo modo el password que introduce el usuario y comparas con el que está guardado en la BD.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu comentario, corregí el dato, y aun no guarda los datos en la tabla :c

Comment: Hola Jose puedes mostrar el error que te sale?, puede que estas poniendo mal algun nombre de tablas o columna, si nos muestras el mensaje de error quizas podamos ayudar

Comment: Veo que el echo no tiene ; al final, pero por favor añade esto luego del insert, `$resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if($resultado === FALSE){
  die(print_r(mysqli_error(), TRUE));
}
else {
echo "Se guardo";
}` y coloca el error si es que existe alguno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualizando la respuesta, debes llamar el método `query()` que es parte del objeto `$conn` como sigue:

```php
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    //si es exitoso
    echo "registro guardado";
} else {
  //si no es exitoso el insert
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Esto solventará tu problema.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu comentario, corregí el dato, y aun no guarda los datos en la tabla , ya puse todo con la sintaxis correcta y aun así nada :c

Comment: He actualizado la soluci'on en base a las nuevas mejoras que has hecho...

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la ayuda, con esto se soluciono mi problema, mil gracias!!

Comment: Excelente, saludos...

Answer (score 0):

En el texto dices que la primera columna en la tabla es `usuario`, pero en tu código veo que intentas guardar algo en una columna llamada `nombre`. ¿Será este el problema?

Comment: Gracias, igual no me había percatado de ese detalle, agradezco que se tomara el tiempo de responder mi duda.